# Hide only Tab Header and not TabItem on count 1

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, itemcontainerstyle

I have a TabControl that creates the TabItems from a ObservableCollection.
So in my ViewModel I already have a boolean Property IsMultiple and already gets set in code. So how do I hide the Tab header completely, but still display the content of that tab.
I have this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding myObservableCollection}" 
 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myTabItemStyle}"
 Style="{StaticResource myTabStyle}">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding myTabHeaderTextProperty}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Basically I want to hide the itemtemplate, note that I cant just hide the TextBlock, because the style then still is there only with empty text. I want to remove/Hide the complete Tab header.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows your attempt, explain what that code does, and how _exactly_ that's different from what you want.

Comment: you want to do this only when there is a single item in your collection, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `Visibility` property of the `ItemContainerStyle` to `Collapsed`:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding myObservableCollection}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>content...</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```